# Distribution law for calculus Which one is right？

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx)+\int_{x1}^{x2}g(x)dx$, I have two results, which one is right?

A. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)+g(x)dx)$

B. $ \int_{x1}^{x2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(x)dx)+\int_{x1}^{x2}g(x)dx$

Thank you

Comment: Is the second integral inside the scope of the partial derivative?  Usually one would put parentheses around the two integrals to show that but people are sloppy sometimes about that.  If so, A is correct.

Comment: It should be like this, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx)+\int_{x1}^{x2}g(x)dx$.

Comment: Then B is correct.  The partial only applies to the first integral.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx$ is a real number, which depends only on $x_1$ and $x_2$. $\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx$ is independent of $t$. Thus

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx)=0.$$

Hence

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\int_{x1}^{x2}f(x)dx)+\int_{x1}^{x2}g(x)dx=\int_{x1}^{x2}g(x)dx.$$